# Start ListView below top of screen

Tags: java, android, xml, listview

I'm trying to add some sort of padding or margin above my `ListView` so that i may add my own custom  navigation bar with images and buttons. I've tried adding both padding and margin to my XML but my `ListView` still appears to start at the top.

How do I start my list view lower then the top of the screen by about `50p` or so?

**Layout**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="com.mycompany.myapp.myActivity"
android:padding="0dp">

<ListView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/theList"
    android:paddingTop="44dp"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/imageView" />


</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Please add your layout xml

Comment: add a picture of what you have and what you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`padding` adds space inside the bounds of the container it is applied to. You want to either use `marginTop` (`margin` adds space outside the bounds of the container it is applied to) on the `ListView` or `paddingTop` on the `RelativeLayout`.

For your case, you should probably use a [`ToolBar`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/Toolbar.html), and place it above your `ListView`. Just giving the `ToolBar` dimensions will push the `ListView` below it if you use a `Linearlayout` instead of a `RelativeLayout` for example.

Comment: I can't seem to find the toolbar. Should it be under widgets?

Comment: `ToolBar` was added in API 21. You can use the support v7 version of it for previous versions. You will need to add `compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.0.3'` to your module's `build.gradle`

Comment: i have this currently `compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.0.3'
`

Comment: Remember you need to fully specify the whole package name of the view when you add it to your XML hierarchy when it is not included on the SDK per-se. In this case it would be `<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>...</ android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>`

Answer (score 0):

Try this piece of code. 
The second `LinearLayout` can be used to hold your custom navigation items of ur choice and let it choose its height.
The listview will automatically fill the rest of the view.

Something similar to this and try margin for `ListView`

```
<LinearLayout
 xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="match_parent"
 android:orientation="vertical"
 tools:context="com.mycompany.myapp.myActivity">

 <LinearLayout
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content">
 <!-- Place your images and buttons need for navigation here -->
 <!-- Also dont forget to choose the appropiate orientation to this layout-->
 </LinearLayout>

<ListView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="fillparent"
    android:id="@+id/theList"/>


</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: This answer does not provide anything different than mine above. Plus, you do not explain why using `margin` instead of `padding` works. Code only answers are discouraged in SO.